# cellForRowAtIndexPath: returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I've got a universal app, and I'm trying to hide a border of a cell, if the next cell in the tableView has an error state. I use this code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to determine if the cell should hide it's bottom border or not:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DCSMCDynamicBaseCell * cell = [self.cellManager dynamicCellForComponent:[self componentForIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath canShowErrors:self.shouldDisplayErrors];

    NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [self.tableView nextRowForIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (nextIndexPath) {
        DCSMCDynamicBaseCell *nextCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nextIndexPath];
        DCSMCDynamicBaseCell *currentCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (nextCell.invalidState) {
            cell.shouldHideBottomBorder = YES;
            NSLog(@"%@", currentCell);
        }
    }

    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[DCSMCDynamicCopyCell class]]) {
        [((DCSMCDynamicCopyCell *)cell).webView setNavigationController:self.navigationController];
    }
    [cell setDelegate:self];

    self.previousIndexPath = indexPath;
    return cell;
}
```

My `nextRowForIndexPath` looks like this:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)nextRowForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger currentRow = indexPath.row;
    NSInteger currentSection = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger numberOfRows = [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSInteger numberOfSections = [self numberOfSections];

    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath;
    if (currentRow + 1 < numberOfRows) {
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentRow + 1 inSection:currentSection];
    } else if (currentSection + 1 > numberOfSections) {
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:currentSection + 1];
    } else {
        newIndexPath = nil;
    }

    return newIndexPath;
}
```

On my iPhone 6 simulator, everything works fine. It gets the cell and hides the bottom border of it. I may refactor this a bit in order to make sure it works in all scenarios, but for a first pass before testing, it works great.

The issue is on the iPad, every single cell returns nil when using the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Even weirder, on iPad, the screen is big enough so that all cells are visible at all times, so when I call reload data, the cells are already visible and should get returned by this method.

Does anyone know why a cell wouldn't get returned by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`on iPad but would on iPhone?

Comment: You shouldn't use cells for storing state. Refer to your data model instead. The next cell may not have been rendered yet, so it is valid for you to get nil

Comment: It would really help if you posted the complete code for your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: Updated to show the entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. The data model is a little janky... The only real place we have it stored for invalid/valid states are in the cell themselves, and it's a massive project, so changing these cells affects 10-15 places in the app... It's an unfortunate scenario. I'm trying to look now for a better way to get the state of the next cell, but as of now this seems to be my only option.

Comment: Are you saying that `cell` is `nil` or that `nextIndexPath` is `nil` on the iPad in your `cellForRow...` method?

Comment: And why aren't you using a normal call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier...` to get a cell from the table view?

Comment: My advice is bite the bullet and fix your data model in the 10-15 places. A bit of work now will save you a world of pain later. Using cells for state is just going to be fragile.  Adding that simple Boolean to the data model will,get rid of 20 lines of order sensitive code in this module alone

Comment: The cell is nil, I'm getting the next index path back correctly from the method. And there's a large amount of code going on behind the scenes for the setup, this is a setup I've inherited to fix a bug, so I'm still not 100% sure what every part is doing. And I may explore that option... It could be a lot easier or a lot harder than I estimated for making a proper model

Comment: If `cell` is `nil` then you have an issue with your cell manager. Use the debugger and see what's happening on the iPad.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, it's actually neither of those that are `nil`, it's `nextCell` that ends up 'nil'. Also, 'currentCell' is nil, which is weird since I know that index path exists (or could it not yet be able to be returned since it hasn't been made by the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method?